# AnalysisServices: Cannot query internal supporting structures for column because they are not processed. Please refresh or recalculate the table

Tags: azure-analysis-services

I'm getting the following error when trying to connect Power BI to my tabular model in AS:
AnalysisServices: Cannot query internal supporting structures for column 'table'[column] because they are not processed. Please refresh or recalculate the table 'table'

It is not a calculated column and the connection seems to work fine on the local copy. I would appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on how you are processing the data within your model.  If you have just done a `Process Data`, then the accompanying meta objects such as relationships have not yet been built.

*Every* column of data that you load needs to also be processed in this way regardless of whether it is a calculated column or not.

This can be achieved by running a `Process Recalc` on the Database or by loading your tables or table partitions with a `Process Full`/`Process Default` rather than just a `Process Data`, which automatically runs the `Process Recalc` once the data is loaded.

If you have a lot of calculated columns and tables that result in a `Process Recalc` taking a long time, you will need to factor this in to your refreshes and model design.

If you run a `Process Recalc` on your database or a `Process Full`/`Process Default` on your table now, you will no longer have those errors in Power BI.

More in depth discussion on this can be found here: http://bifuture.blogspot.com/2017/02/ssas-processing-tabular-model.html